# CORS when using axios but works normal using curl

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to use `GET` from an API(not mine). I test it using simple `curl` it works normal, but when I try to use `axios`, `axios` sends `OPTION`. Server only accepts `GET,HEAD,POST` so its throw `CORS`

Any idea why `axios` sends `OPTION`, not `GET`?

Here's my `curl`

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://xxxxxx'
]);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Here's my `axios`

```
export default {
    data: {
        users:[]
    },
      mounted(){
         this.loadData();
      },
  methods:{
     loadData:function(){
        axios.get('https://xxxxxxxx')
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
        });  
     }
  }
}
```

is it problem with the server or i miss something?

Comment: You are using cURL from the server side, and the browser is not involved. It is the client browser that enforces cross-origin policy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I create an API that fetches data from outside API. Since it works in simple curl, I use that curl in Axios and working. It's not efficient but it's working :)

Answer (score -3):

In your laravel press ctrl+p then write Verifycsrftoken and inside
protected $except = [ 'stripe/*',    `enter code here`'http://example.com/foo/*',    //any route ];

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with CSRF.

Comment: What does Ctrl+p do?